# redirecting just a single non-www homepage to www version, without redirecting any other pages

Tags: redirect

I need to redirect the non-www version of just a single page, the homepage, to www.

I want to leave the rest of the site alone. Due to a need to keep a specific page non www.

So if i try a rewrite rule of

/index.html http://www.example.com/

I get a infinite redirect type error.

Comment: Is this with Apache? Nginx? Something else?

Comment: http://www.example.com --> http://www.example.com/index.html ---> http://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a way to achieve what you want, although I must say that this has a bit of a "smell" to it. It sounds like you are trying to treat a single symptom rather than fix a problem (which, admittedly might be beyond your control). Is it possible that your organization needs to setup a domain pointer so that www.example.com and examples.com are the exact same thing?

Comment: Yes you are right about the smell. It is a joomla bug, which means I have to keep a certain page non-www or a redirect to a payment gateway fails. So all links are hard coded www. but this means that i'm losing seo juice sent to non-www version of the site

Comment: Do you have control of the DNS records? On my webservers, www is aliased to the domain itself so that requests to example.com/index.html are the exact same as www.example.com/index.html. It might be a cleaner way to fix things.

Answer (score 0):

So you want

- `http://example.com/` to go to `http://www.example.com/`,

but you want

- `http://example.com/index.html`,
- `http://example.com/otherstuff`, and
- `http://example.com/subdir/path/file.php`

to stay the same?

For Apache:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

If you want any non-www subdomain on the site to get redirected to the www version:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

If you want to redirect everything except a specific page:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/path/file.php$ 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```